# GridView images are not shown using Picasso Lib

Tags: android, gridview, picasso

I am using the Picasso library to load images in a GridView. Here is my code.First I have a class that contains String array of links.For experimental purposes I use the same image.

```
  public class Data {

  static final String[] URLS = {
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502",
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502",
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502",
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502",
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502",
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502",
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502",

 };

  private Data() {
 // No instances.
 }
}
```

Next I have the MainActivity Class which does the usual stuff,ie initializing the GridView etc.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gv.setAdapter(new SampleGridViewAdapter(this));
    gv.setOnScrollListener(new SampleScrollListener(this));

  }

}
```

Finally I have the GridViewAdapter that I created.

```
final class SampleGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final Context context;
private final List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();

public SampleGridViewAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    // Ensure we get a different ordering of images on each run.
    Collections.addAll(urls, Data.URLS);
    Collections.shuffle(urls);

    // Triple up the list.
    ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(urls);
    urls.addAll(copy);
    urls.addAll(copy);
 }


@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup   
parent)   {
    SquaredImageView view = (SquaredImageView) convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = new SquaredImageView(context);
        view.setScaleType(CENTER_CROP);
    }

    // Get the image URL for the current position.
    String url = getItem(position);

    // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
    Picasso.with(context) //
            .load(url) //
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
            .error(R.drawable.error) //
            .fit() //
            .tag(context) //
            .into(view);

    return view;
}

@Override public int getCount() {
    return urls.size();
}

@Override public String getItem(int position) {
    return urls.get(position);
}

@Override public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The urls you are passing is not an actual image url, it takes to the webpage.

I inspected and extracted image url for one of the url. Use this it will work.
http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/116726502.jpg

Make sure you have the actual image url while loading the images in the app

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't see the images in the gridview. When you say that I must have the actual image url,you mean to put it in an imageview?

Comment: no i mean there is a difference between this two urls http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502 and http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/116726502.jpg. The one you use doesn't return just an image, it basically returns the whole webpage whereas the url i shared in my answer return only the image. Try loading both the url in the browser, you will come to know

Comment: It doesn't work with http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/116726502.jpg either.

Comment: resize the image before loading like this Picasso.with(context).load(url).centerCrop().resize(200, 200).into(view);

Comment: hope you have the internet connection or ur device?

Comment: yes i have. I aslo put  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> in the manifest file. I am doing something wrong else and can not see it.

Comment: Do I aslo have to use the PicassoSampleActivity class?

Comment: from here? https://github.com/square/picasso/tree/master/picasso-sample/src/main/java/com/example/picasso

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to change url to real photo url

e.g.

```
http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/116726502.jpg
```

Comment: It's doesn't work with that way either. Maybe i did something wrong inside the GridView Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL Array is not correct.. check that and make a valid array of URL. That array may be like..

```
static final String[] URLS = {
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502.jpg",
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502.jpg",
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502.jpg",
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502.jpg",
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502.jpg",
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502.jpg",
    "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/116726502.jpg",

 };

  private Data() {
 // No instances.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found some time post the solution to this problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GridView gridView;
private GridviewAdapter gridAdapter;


String[] items = {
        "http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/116726502.jpg",
        "http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/116726502.jpg",
        "http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/116726502.jpg",
        "http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/116726502.jpg",
        "http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/116726502.jpg",
        "http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/116726502.jpg",
        "http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/116726502.jpg",
        "http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/116726502.jpg",
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);


    gridAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);


    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

  }
}
```

And an adapter that does the usual stuff.

```
public class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context context;
private String[] items;


public GridviewAdapter(Context context, String[] items){
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView img = null;
    if (convertView == null) {

        img = new ImageView(context);

        convertView = img;
        img.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    } else {
        img = (ImageView) convertView;
    }



    Picasso.with(context)

        .load(items[position])

        .placeholder(R.drawable.picture)
        .resize(200, 200)

        .into(img);

    return convertView;
    }

}
```

Hope this is going to be useful for someone...